# Invalid Bearer Access Token

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, rsa, hapi.js

We are using `hapi-auth-jwt2` alongside `jwks-rsa` to decode and verify azureAD access token.

This is our jwt strategy which is active on every route.

```
'use strict'

const jwt = require('hapi-auth-jwt2')
const jwksRsa = require('jwks-rsa')
const userCtrl = require('./../controllers/UserController')
const authHandler = require('./auth.factory').GetAuthHandler()

// TODO: Replace with current JSON web token formatting and active directory

module.exports = {
  name: 'JWT Authentication',
  register: async (server, options) => {
    await server.register(jwt)
    // Confirm that we are getting the correct PK
    // const pk = await authHandler.GetPK()
    const key = jwksRsa.hapiJwt2KeyAsync({
      cache: true,
      rateLimit: true,
      jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
      // jwksUri: 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/.well-known/jwks.json'
      jwksUri: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys'
      // https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys
      // https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration
    })

    server.auth.strategy('jwt', 'jwt', {
      // Get the complete decoded token, because we need info from the header (the kid)
      complete: true,
      // Dynamically provide a signing key based on the kid in the header and the singing keys provided by the JWKS endpoint.
      key: key,
      // key: pk,
      headerKey: 'authorization',
      tokenType: 'Bearer',
      validate: userCtrl.validate,
      verifyOptions: {
        algorithms: ['RS256'] // or HS256 RS256
      }
    })
    server.auth.default('jwt')
    console.log(key)
  }
}
```

We then attach `Authorization` header (i.e. `'Bearer ' + accessToken`) to `http` and make a request from `locahost` i.e. current client/front-end to the `/sso` route and the server comes back with the following request/response

```
[1569928136140] INFO  (11252 on PORT230): request completed
    req: {
      "id": "1569928136137:PORT230:11264:k17qg99b:10001",
      "method": "get",
      "url": "https://port230.5874.com/api/v2/user/sso",
      "headers": {
        "host": "port230.5874.com",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "origin": "http://localhost:8080",
        "authorization": "Bearer ...",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
        "referer": "http://localhost:8080/",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
      }
    }
    res: {
      "statusCode": 401,
      "headers": {
        "www-authenticate": "Bearer error=\"Invalid token\"",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "vary": "origin",
        "access-control-allow-origin": "http://localhost:8080",
        "access-control-expose-headers": "WWW-Authenticate,Server-Authorization",
        "strict-transport-security": "max-age=15768000",
        "x-frame-options": "DENY",
        "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
        "x-download-options": "noopen",
        "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "content-length": 106
      }
    }
    responseTime: 3
```

The response includes `"www-authenticate": "Bearer error=\"Invalid token\""`. We have been trying to understand why is there an `Invalid Token` error but without much success.

Would anybody know when and why is this error thrown and potentially how to overcome it?

Comment: does the `...` in  `"authorization": "Bearer ..."` look correct to you?

Comment: @JaromandaX For logical reasons the access token is not included in the req above. Using jwt.io the token can be decoded but not when using jwt strategy

Comment: I'm not asking you to show the token, I'm asking is it correct

Comment: @JaromandaX well this is where the problems lays since it comes back as invalid. How can we confirm if it is correct? we acquire it by making a `getToken` (part of MSAL.js) call on our front-end then we return `accessTokenResponse.accessToken` and attach it to the http header

Comment: not sure what you mean by *can be decoded but not when using jwt strategy* - surely jwt.io can decode the header and payload?

Comment: I mean that by using jwt.io we input the access token and get a decoded JSON object back. Doing the same but through `hapi-auth-jwt2` `auth.strategy` (as shown in the question) we are returned `Invalid Token`

Comment: @bba278 Are you acquiring an `access token` for Microsoft Graph, and trying to send it to your own web api?

Comment: Could you tell me how you acquire Azure AD access token?

Comment: @TiagoBrenck we are acquiring an `access token` with `acquireTokenSilent`, or `acquireTokenPopup` if the previous fails and then we attach the token to the http header like this `Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token`. I presume that the token comes from Microsoft Graph. After the token is attached we call `axios.get` to our `login` back-end route

Comment: @JimXu please see my reply to TiagoBrenck

Comment: Can you use the access token to call the graph api? Besides, can you use the same way to validate the access token with other Azure AD resources successfully?

Comment: @JimXu Apologies but I'm not sure what you mean when you say to use the access token to call the graph api. We haven't tried validating other azure AD resources at this stage. One thing I noticed is that our decoded header object returned with jwt.io consists of "typ", "nonce", "alg", "x5t", "kid". Also, our App registraion has `Microsoft Graph` with `User.Read`selected under required permissions currently

Comment: @JimXu we now understand what the call to the graph API does. However, is it not possible to not make this call and purely make something like an implicit grant? Do we need to pass another token for this to be achieved, maybe the ID token that comes back?

Comment: @bba278 my point is, if you get an access token for Microsoft Graph, you can **only** use it to consume Microsoft Graph. It **won't** work if you use the Graph access token to consume your own custom API.

Comment: According to my understanding, you use your code to validate Microsoft graph access token then you get the error ```Invalid token```. Is that right?

Comment: @JimXu after a lot of reading we understood that instead of trying to validate a token through Microsoft Graph we should have defined a scope for our API inside `portal.azure.com` and then create API permission with the newly created scope. Making a call with MSAL then generated a valid token which JWT was able to decode. Problem solved. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @bba278 Since your issue has been resolved, could you please post your answer? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that we hadn't defined the scopes for our API on [https://portal.azure.com](http://%20https://portal.azure.com) correctly. After we fixed that we created API permission with the newly created scope, hence the access token was successfully decoded